# ASP.net MVC unable to call POST Logout method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been trying to perform Logout operation (Form Authentication with cookies) but unable to call the POST Logout action method.

Here's my Partial View:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Logoff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) 
     { 
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" title="Logout">
        <img alt="Home" src="@Url.Content(" ~/Images/logout.png ")"/>

      </a>
      }

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

I'm calling this partial View in below Home page as header:

```
<header role="banner">

    @Html.Partial("_HomeHeader")

</header>

<div class="container">
.......
</div>
```

In my account controller, I've defined following action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Logoff()
{    
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
      Session.Clear();
      return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);                
}
```

Thus, on clicking the Logout button from the home page, it should Go to the "Logoff" action method and clear the cookies and then redirect to Login Page.
But it doesn't work.
Instead, it goes to the Login page directly without visiting the Logoff action method. I got this URL: 
http://localhost/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogoff

Can anyone please provide their inputs regarding how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You typically get the `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=blah` when the page you are trying to visit requires authentication and you are unauthenticated or have insufficient privileges.

Comment: In this case, `Logoff` action method requires authentication to access it and probably `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` removes auth cookie during the logout process - try marking `Logoff` action method with `AllowAnonymousAttribute`.

Comment: Adding [AllowAnonymous] Attribute worked for me. Thanks Tetsuya.

Comment: Adding `[AllowAnonymous]` would make no sense. It would mean that you were never logged in in the first place so what would be the point of logging out

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for information. Here's the breakdown: 
When I click on the Logout button, without any [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous] attribute, my Logoff action method is not visited, instead the Login (GET) action method is getting called.
Thus, following scenario is occurring:
Login (GET) --> Login(POST)--> Home Page (click logout button on Home Page)  --> **Login (GET)**
instead it should have been this:
Login (GET) --> Login(POST)--> Home Page (click logout button on Home Page)  --> **Logoff(POST)**
Thus, a GET is called instead of POST.
Please suggest some input?

Answer (score 0):

I know you already far in the process but you could use the WebSecurity method instead of your action method in your action controller... (OathWebsecurity, WebSecurity.Logout();... etc)

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, Hope it Helps.!

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:submitform()" title="Logout">
    <img alt="Home" src="@Url.Content(" ~/Images/logout.png ")"/>
  </a>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  function submitform()
  {
    $("#logoutForm").submit();
  }   
</script>
```